# sql save results in variable and later use it for update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using MSSQL2017

Lets say I have a Table called Partner, this Table has an ID and a delete Flag.
And I have a second Table called PatnerAdress, this Table has a PatnerID and some data.
And lets say there are 5 more Tables like PatnerComunication (PartnerID, Email, someData...), PartnerSomething1, PartnerSomething2, PartnerSomething3.

Now I would like to do something like this:

Is this even possible and if yes what Type do I have to use for my @IDsToDelete?

```
DECLARE @IDsToDelete someTypeIDontKnow;

SET @IDsToDelete = (SELECT ID FROM Partner WHERE delete = 1)

DELETE PatnerAdress WHERE PartnerID IN @IDsToDelete
DELETE PatnerComunication WHERE PartnerID IN @IDsToDelete
DELETE PartnerSomething1 WHERE PartnerID IN @IDsToDelete
DELETE PartnerSomething2 WHERE PartnerID IN @IDsToDelete
DELETE PartnerSomething3 WHERE PartnerID IN @IDsToDelete
```

Comment: There is no native array type in SQL Server, but there are various approaches. See [this article](https://sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html) for an overview.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **table variable**. it gives as mush as value as you want.
then you can use **Join in Delete**  meaning join your table with table variable.

```
DECLARE @a table (IDsToDelete int ) 
insert into @a 
(SELECT ID FROM Partner WHERE delete = 1)
--delete  statment
delete  PA from 
PatnerAdress  PA
join @a a on a.IDsToDelete=PA.PartnerID
```

or simply **Delete**

```
DELETE PatnerAdress WHERE PartnerID IN 
(select * from @a)
```

In addition you can use **temporary table** or **global temporary table**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temptable ;
SELECT ID 
into #temptable --create temporary table
FROM Partner WHERE delete = 1
DELETE PatnerAdress WHERE PartnerID IN 
(select * from #temptable)
```

Comment: A table variable is indeed one way to do it, but not what you've written here, which will not compile.

Comment: thanks for trying to help me I figured it out and posted it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (v varchar(64));

insert into @t (v) 
  SELECT ID from Partner WHERE delete = 1

DELETE PatnerAdress WHERE PartnerID in (select v from @t)
DELETE PatnerComunication WHERE PartnerID in (select v from @t)
DELETE PartnerSomething1 WHERE PartnerID in (select v from @t)
DELETE PartnerSomething2 WHERE PartnerID in (select v from @t)
DELETE PartnerSomething3 WHERE PartnerID in (select v from @t)
```